# Highcharts - print large format chart but keep text small

Tags: highcharts, printing-web-page

I have a lot of sunburst charts made using Highcharts that are displayed on a web page - an example is below.

What I would like to do is to be able to print these on A1 or A0 paper (to use as a wall display) - but when I try to scale them everything gets bigger, including the text. I would like to keep the text small so that when the chart is printed, all of the text displays and none overflows.

[Sunburst Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBtLI.png)

Does anyone have any suggestion how I could achieve this?

I've tried saving as various different formats. My next idea would be to perhaps use CSS

Comment: I'd start by making the html chart larger and explore how things scale at different sizes (e.g., 1000px, 2000px [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2rs3h9Lt/)) and then set options accordingly, mainly for font sizes, either in javascript or css. If you have a very specific look in mind you'll have to experiment with the options until you achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can define font size via `exporting.chartOptions`

**Example config:**

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  series: [{
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true
    },
    data: [1, 2, 3, 4]
  }],

  exporting: {
    enabled: true,
    chartOptions: {
      plotOptions: {
        series: {
          dataLabels: {
            style: {
              fontSize: '56px'
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ar49cbfh/

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting.chartOptions

Comment: Thank you - sorry for the late reply.  I will try this method